# Farm WebApp url change

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I recently setup a 3 tier farm with a wfe an app server and sql server. When creating the apps in central admin i didn't notice the app url was the app server and not the web front end, how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the web application, be default all the url points to the APp server.

You have to make the changes in the **Alternate Access Mapping**, `From Central admin   > Application Management > Configure alternate access mappings`

From this page the select the Web Application **from Right dropdown** **select the web application**. now you can edit the URL here.

After that make sure IIS settings are correct on WFE, for the web application(proper port number bind it)...all the time its correct but just for making sure.

Also if their is any web.config changes or any customization make sure applied to the WFE.

Comment: Thanks, so what is the best practice approach when creating apps should the url be the app server and then add the access mapping url for the wfe or set the url of the app to the wfe when creating the app?

Comment: I would set to WFE while creating the Web apps. But you can change it any time.

Comment: So is an alternate access mapping a redirect and will the traffic actually go through the wwb front end if i set the aam?

Comment: if you set the WFE url in AAM then WFE will respond but if you have APP server URL in AAM then APP server will respond.